# Display/hide h:panelGrid on the base of value selected in h:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to display and hide a `<h:panelGrid>` on the basis of the value selected in `<h:selectOneMenu>`.

The code is:

```
<p:dialog id="logClassDlg" header="Log Class Teached" widgetVar="logClass" modal="true" >
    <h:form>
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
        <h:panelGrid id="logClassPanelGrd1" columns="2">

            <h:outputLabel for="class" value="Class: " />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="class" value="#{logClassBean.classLog.classTitle}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Reading" itemLabel="Reading" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Memorization" itemLabel="Memorization" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Translation" itemLabel="Translation" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Language" itemLabel="Language" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Grammer" itemLabel="Grammer" />
                <f:ajax render="logClassPanelGrdBook" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>

        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid id="logClassPanelGrdBook" columns="2" rendered="#{(logClassBean.classLog.classTitle ne 'Language') and (logClassBean.classLog.classTitle ne 'Grammar')}">
            <p:outputLabel value="Book" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="book" value="#{logClassBean.classLog.classStatus}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="first" itemLabel="first" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="second" itemLabel="second" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="third" itemLabel="third" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="fourth" itemLabel="fourth" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="fifth" itemLabel="fifth" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGrid>
```

As you can see I want to display the panel grid `logClassPanelGrdBook` only on when the selected values are not Language and Grammar i.e

```
rendered="#{(logClassBean.classLog.classTitle ne 'Language') and (logClassBean.classLog.classTitle ne 'Grammar')}"
```

But the panel grid is displayed irrespective of the values selected, it should hide when the other values (Reading, Memorization and Translation) are selected.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part `<f:ajax render="logClassPanelGrdBook" />` won't update and recheck the rendered function of the panelGrid this way. You will need to update its parent element instead.

For example, you can wrap it with `<h:panelGroup>`:

```
        <h:panelGrid id="logClassPanelGrd1" columns="2">

            <h:outputLabel for="class" value="Class: " />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="class" value="#{logClassBean.classLog.classTitle}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Reading" itemLabel="Reading" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Memorization" itemLabel="Memorization" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Translation" itemLabel="Translation" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Language" itemLabel="Language" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Grammar" itemLabel="Grammar" />
                <f:ajax render="logClassPanelGrdBook" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>

        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGroup id="logClassPanelGrdBook">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{(logClassBean.classLog.classTitle ne 'Language') and (logClassBean.classLog.classTitle ne 'Grammar')}">
            <p:outputLabel value="Book" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="book" value="#{logClassBean.classLog.classStatus}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="first" itemLabel="first" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="second" itemLabel="second" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="third" itemLabel="third" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="fourth" itemLabel="fourth" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="fifth" itemLabel="fifth" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGroup>
```

I also changed select item value from Grammer to Grammar because it didn't match the value in rendered attribute.

If this doesn't work, you should also check if bean value is properly set when you click `<h:selectOneMenu>`.

Comment: Thankyou. Had already figured out that i had to render @form. Thanks for your help.
PS: the Grammer thing was edited by user: Tiny, the original code wasn't like that. Thanks for your help.